# Can I be reasonably certain that IRS website is genuine?

Tags: spoofing

https://www.irs.gov/identity-theft-fraud-scams/identity-verification

I received a letter in the mail indicating that I need to verify my ID with the IRS. Can I be reasonably certain that the website is actually the IRS?  Why / How?

Comment: Google the IRS.

Comment: If anyone sees a problem with the question, please provide more feedback than downvoting.  Ideal feedback: a correction to the question.

Comment: If you hover over the buttons, there are canned downvoting reasons. One of them is "does not show research effort". One can't correct for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you Google the IRS you will see:

- irs.gov is the top hit
- irs.gov is in the Google info box on the side
- wikipedia lists irs.gov as the official website
- Twitter lists the official, verified IRS account as having irs.gov as the homepage

In addition:

- [.gov websites are not available to the public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gov)
- The official government page for America lists irs.gov as the official website

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In general, to be reasonably sure, you need to ensure:

1. You haven't installed random root certificates on your computer (for most people that's true)
2. The root URL says https://irs.gov
3. There is a lock icon on your web browser.

To ensure an extra degree of reasonability, you will need to ensure:

1. Your computer manufacturer is trusted
2. No root certificate authorities have been hacked
3. Your browser hasn't been maliciously modified
4. The irs website hasn't been hacked

We rely on certificate authorities to ensure the domain we navigate to leads to the correct website.

Comment: All of this would be true and pass your tests for any domain, including `the-real-irs-really.info` Certificates to not certify that the site is genuine.